# How to open an existing JPR file in JDeveloper

Tags: oracle, soa, jdeveloper, osb

Goodday,

Recently I received an Oracle Service Bus project. It's pretty large and has several OSB components in it. In order to work on these OSB components, I need to open the project in JDeveloper.
The project was created with JDeveloper 12.2.1.3 back then by someone else and now I'm picking it up again to fix some issues.

Now, I've installed Oracle SOA Quick Start 12.2.1.3 (as newer versions won't work with the code). With that SOA suite, JDeveloper is installed. With JDeveloper opened, I want to import the existing project which is a `.jpr` file. But JDeveloper only recognizes `.jws` files and not `.jpr` files, so... game over?
I know this 12.2.1.3 version should be able to open `.jpr` files, as this whole project was created by someone who made it in this version. I also tried to download and install the standalone JDeveloper, but that didn't work at all (that standalone version is not able to read OSB components anyway).

So, is there another plugin I require in order to open .jpr files? Or am I just missing something else here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need a plugin or anything else. You can create a custom workspace in Jdev, without any project. This will create the `.jws` file. Once you have the workspace, you can copy the whole project into the workspace folder. Then you open the project from within the workspace and the project will be loaded.